# Error C2270: Modifiers not allowed on nonmember functions

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, compiler-errors, modifiers, non-member-functions

I'm getting this error when compiling:

error C2270: 'busco' : modifiers not allowed on nonmember functions

I think I understand the reason but I don't know how to fix it, if I take the `const` out I get a C2662 error.

Here is the code:

```
    template <class T>
    class ABBImp: public ABB<T> {
    public:
        const T& Recuperar(const T &e) const ;
    private:
        NodoABB<T> * busco(NodoABB<T> * arbol,T &e) const;
    protected:
        NodoABB<T>* arbol;
    };

    template <class T>
//If I take this const out I get the other error I talked about
    NodoABB<T>* busco(NodoABB<T> * arbol,T &e)const{
        if(a!=NULL){
            if(arbol->dato==e)
                return arbol;
            else if (arbol->dato<e)
                return busco(arbol->der,e);
            else
                return busco(arbol->izq,e);
        }else{
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    template <class T>
    const T& ABBImp<T>::Recuperar(const T &e) const{
        NodoABB<T> * aux=busco(arbol,e);
        return aux->dato;
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have an error C2270 because your `busco` function is a free template function, it does not belong to a class. So `const` makes no sense on the signature : remove it.

If you intended this function to be a member function, place its definition at the point of declaration (I guess the `ABBImp` class), or prefix the declaration with the class name as you did for the `Recuperar` function.

Comment: +1 -- note that it *is* declared in the class, so your second paragraph is probably what the OP wants.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realized that I was forgeting that.